# Cannot convert value of type 'UITouch.Type' to expected argument type 'Set<UITouch>'

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a function so that when the bird touches one of the pipes something should happen (which i will write down later) but right away i got an error and i don't know how to fix it.

It is "UITouch" part that gets the error I've already tried to put multiple different codes there but i don't know what i should write there.

If you know the answer please tell me. :)

```
func ifCollidedWith() {
    if bird.touchesBegan(UITouch, withEvent: pipePair){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an SKSpriteNode to call touchesBegan. touchesBegan is a method that runs when the screen is tapped, not when a node interacts with another node. If you want to detect a collision you need to give the node a physics body. Create a enum and use that to assign category bit masks, collision bit masks and contact bit mask between your sprite nodes. This may sound confusing, so here is a guide to help you: [Ray Wenderlich Swift SpriteKit for Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners)